# How to use Core Text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-text

I have a basic implementation of **Core Text** that prints Hello World in iOS, it works perfectly with UIKit.

```
import UIKit
import CoreText

class CTView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        // Flip the coordinate system
        context.textMatrix = .identity
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(bounds)
        
        let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World")
        
        let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString as CFAttributedString)
        
        let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), path, nil)
        
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context)
    }
}
```

I've tried to use this Core Text with SwiftUI instead of UIKit by applying the use of `UIViewRepresentable`:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreText

struct CTView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to implement (or basically, override) the draw function, since we use structs instead of classes in SwiftUI.

In addition to that, how can we do the same thing for macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your previous `CTView`, as in

```
struct WrappedCTView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CTView {
        let view = CTView()       // << here !!
        view.isOpaque = false
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CTView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but the app is displaying a black background instead of displaying the Hello World text. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/8673/iIUH2A.png

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you also answer the second part of question: